# Call Web Service from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services

I have a web service with a web method which echoes whatever you pass it.

I try to call my web method from T-SQL code but it neither works nor yields any exception or error.

Here's the code:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
    'http://vserver250:8600/EcomSmsSvc.asmx/Reply?message=hi','false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

My web service works fine, and when I call it through web browsers it returns the message I send it, but when I call it from T-SQL the result is always `NULL`.

Can anyone help me find out where the problem is?

Comment: If you really must call a web service from T-SQL (a bad idea, in my opinion) then I'd recommend using the SQLCLR functionality (rather than the clunky old `sp_OAmethod` approach). Create a C# stored procedure using SQL-CLR and deploy it into SQL Server

Comment: thanks for providing a neat solution @marc_s. Can you tell me how with giving an example please?

Comment: Search Google or Bing for "using sql-clr calling stored procedure" - there's **tons** of material on this. I don't have a specific link that I could recommend - you'll need to do some research yourself!

Comment: See this link for a starting point: [Call a WCF Service from SQLCLR](http://nielsb.wordpress.com/sqlclrwcf/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it using a **web service client built in .NET**. I suppose this would be a cleaner solution, more maintainable and easier to test and debug.

[In this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/11/25/how-to-consume-a-web-service-from-within-sql-server-using-sql-clr.aspx) you could find such an example.

Hope I helped!